# Get Values from Json Object and implement jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui

Get the values from the ajax response that is in json object format work and implement the autocomplete by jQuery autocomplete box.

```
{ "consignmentList" : [ "" , "AAA" , "ABC" , "BHU" , "MAN" , "WER" , "ZXC"]}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input#autoText").autocomplete({
    width: 300,
    max: 10,
    delay: 100,
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: true,
    cacheLength: 1,
    scroll: true,
    highlight: false,
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/jqueryreturn",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: request,
        success: function(data) {
          //console.log( data);
          var items = data;
          response(items);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          //console.log( textStatus);
        }
      });
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<link href="http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/js/jquery/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/js/jquery/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/js/jquery/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/js/jquery/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/js/jquery/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="autoText" type="text" class="inputlt" name="consignmentId" value="${(consign._id)!" "}" id="c" style="font-size: 16px " onclick="clearInput(this)">
<ul id="consignmentList"></ul>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question, there isn't a question mark in your post.

Comment: my question is how i can retrieve the values from json object and for that where should i edit this code to get the auto-complete box with these values which are in json object

Answer (score 0):

In your success handler, invoke response() with items.consignmentList

```
success: function(data) {
    var items = data;
    response(items.consignmentList);
}
```

Your server sends back JSON which is parsed by jQuery automatically into a JavaScript object. This is because you have set the dataType to be 'json'.

So, `data` variable within your success callback is a regular JS object with *one* property `consignmentList`.

You access the property as `items.consignmentList` which gives an array of string that you want to be autocompleted.